# JSONArray length seems to be wrong and therefore won't iterate correctly

Tags: java, android-studio

I am stuck on the following problem and I havent been able to find a solution after a couple hours of googling and trying different solutions.

I have a JSONArray similar to the following:

```
[
 {
  "id":"3000",
  "ref":"Order100",
  "extraOptions": { "someOption":"1" }
 },
 {
  "id":"3001",
  "ref":"Order101",
  "extraOptions": { "someOption":"1" }
 },
 {
  
  "id":"3002",
  "ref":"Order102",
  "extraOptions": { "someOption":"1" }
 }
]
```

If I understand this correctly then this JSONArray contains 3 JSONObjects, right?

Well, I have the following code to iterate over the JSONArray:

```
public void processFinish(JSONArray response){
        ArrayList<String> partnerList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
            try {
                JSONObject rec = response.getJSONObject(i);
                partnerList.add(rec.getString("ref"));
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        purchaseOrders = 1;
        fillList(partnerList);
}
```

Now, for reasons I do not understand, response.length() returns 1, and when the for loop is done it only shows one entry in my list. What kind of mistake am I making here/what am I missing?
Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

EDIT: The problem seems to be in my AsyncTask onPostExecute(String s) function which looks like the following.

```
@Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s){
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                if(s != null){
                    try {
                        System.out.println(s);
                        JSONArray resp = new JSONArray(s);
                        delegate.processFinish(resp);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
```

I get the JSON from the API of a Web-App. This Web-App also offers the possibility to test the API on page and shows you what the Response Body looks like. So I changed String s and just copied the Response Body from the Webpage into there and with that it seems to work just fine and iterate over it correctly.

However when I use the API as intented like in the function above, it does not work.

EDIT2: Problem solved. Find the answer by me below in the answer section.
Thank you to the people that tried to help me and steered  me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you sure your JSON is valid? After your "ref"-field in every Object in the array should be a comma, and as far as I know JSON typically uses ":" instead of "=". Your JSON parses properly with these changes applied.

Comment: @amsjntz My bad, I wrote the JSON myself since there is sensible info in the real one, will change it right away. But yes the actual JSON is valid.

Comment: are you sure about the validity of your JSON? I'm failing to recreate your issue, for me, "response.length()" returns three as it should.

Comment: @amsjntz I found where the problem lies, but not what causes it or what the problem itself is. I will make an edit to the post to explain.

Comment: Can you print `response` to see how it actually looks like?

Comment: @QBrute I already did and the JSON was too long to just print. So now I logged it and it actually is just one JSONObject that the API returns, not 3 as it is supposed to. I feel incredibly stupid as I have worked to fix this error for the past 3 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API was not returning the correct amount of JSON Objects, thats why it was only showing 1 entry in the list. I should have tested that before I asked the question.
Again thank you to everyone that tried to help.